# Asp.net Hosted application do not Access in Intranet (LAN) With Host Header While It Is Accessing When Host Header Remove via IP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, host, lan

i am trying to access hosted asp.net application in intranet (LAN) via Host header it do not found web while in the mean time it can be access if i remove host header via ip address and port ?

i host application on port 80 with host header,

```
scoring.com is host header with port 80
```

it is accessible in local system but do not access on LAN on other systems,

```
http://scoring.com

server not found error
```

after that when i remove host header and just call it via IP on other system over network as well as local system it works fine like,

```
http://192.168.1.4:80
```

what configuration is missing that it is not working on local network when host header apply to it ??

Hopes for your suggestions Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your host name is not registered in the DNS.

You can test this by running `ping [hostname]` command, If the output is `Ping request could not find host [hostname]` then it's not registered, or `nslookup [hostname]` command.

Comment: i will have to register host name some thing like this "C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set site /site.name:Design /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:scoring']"

Comment: every system in network will have to register it for accessing  this application ?

Comment: No, by default IIS won't filter requests based on the HOST header. I was referring the DNS - Domain Name System, which is responsible for translating host names like stackoverflow.com to ip addresses.

Comment: ok is it necessary that network must have domain for registering domain name ? because i am getting error while registering (appcmd is not recognize as internal or external command) on Xp machine ??

Comment: You can't use appcmd.exe (an iis utility) for registering a domain name. Does the DNS server belong to you (you can check this by running ipconfig /all and look for DNS Servers)? Is your site accessible from the internet?